# Phalcon INVO project register process fails

Tags: php, phalcon

I set up the INVO project of Phalcon to get used to the framework. However, I'm facing a problem with the register process. When I try to register, I get the error

```
 Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Phalcon\Mvc\Model::validate() must implement interface Phalcon\ValidationInterface, instance of Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Email given in C:\xampp\htdocs\invo\app\models\Users.php on line 13
```

I haven't changed anything code-wise and I searched Google for a solution to this, but I haven't found anything. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Phalcon 2.1 beta but INVO uses stable 2.0

Comment: Well, now I'm getting the `Class 'Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini' not found` error...

Comment: Create an issue to the INVO repo

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna do that!